# HTTP post NSString into php file on server

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, http-post

I need to post an NSString into a file on my website. I've created a file at http://www.mysite.herokuapp.com/newFile.php and need to post data into newFile.php.

I found this [Send String to webserver in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553402/send-string-to-webserver-in-ios) earlier, which I thought was perfect, but soon realized was from 2009/2010 and the code wasn't working. After fiddling with it for a bit, I got the code below, but it doesn't work.

So there are two parts to this:

First, should I even be posting into a .php file in the first place? Would .txt be easier?

Second, how do I do this on the website end and the iOS end?

Here is the code I've put together in iOS:

```
// Post data onto external server
             NSString *post = @"IsThisWorking?";
             NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

             NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

             NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
             [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mysite.herokuapp.com/getLikes.php"]];
             [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
             [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
             [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
             [request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to handle this on your server.

the method that receives the `NSString` - which in your example `getLikes.php` - should save the string to a file on the server.

i'm not familial with PHP, but this link might help

[php - file write](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php)

Answer (score 0):

### iOS end

Get ASIHttpRequest or AFNetworking.

I used ASIHttpRequest and its ASIFormData because I found AFNetworking had some POST variable bugs:

```
-(void)postDataToServer
{
    NSURl url = [NSURL urlWithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/api/submitdata"];

    __block ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setPostValue:myString forKey:@"data"];

    [request setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"Server response = %@", [request responseString]);
    }];

    [request setFailedBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"Server error: %@", [[request error] localizedDescription];
    }];

    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

### PHP Server end

I would be using a web framework like Symfony to build the web service but for a quick and dirty solution, you could do the following to quickly test:

```
class API
{
    public function saveData()
    {
        if(isset($_REQUEST['data']))
        {
            // google some php code to write to file
        }
    }
}

// when the page loads, we call the saveData and in there
// we check if data is passed in
$api = new API();
$api->saveData();
```